# NoSQL é sinônimo de Banco de Dados Orientado a Objetos?

Tags: banco-de-dados, nosql

NoSQL é sinônimo de Banco de Dados Orientado a Objetos?

Se a resposta for **não**: Qual a diferença entre os dois?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Está havendo aqui uma confusão de conceitos na sua pergunta. Mas respondendo em essência, **não, não são sinônimos**.

**NoSQL** designa bancos de dados que usam tecnologias que não a de um banco de dados relacional, **não necessariamente sendo orientados a objetos**. NoSQL, por sinal, significa *Not Only SQL*. Isto quer dizer que o banco de dados em questão pode (ou não) responder sentenças SQL. Normalmente os bancos de dados respondem sentenças em formato próprio ou em outros formatos conhecidos (como o [json](/questions/tagged/json), por exemplo).

[O artigo da Wikipédia em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) separa estes bancos de dados em várias taxonomias, sendo a mais importante o formato como cada banco de dados armazena a informação:

- **Como Coluna**

  - Accumulo, Cassandra, HBase
- **Como Documento**

  - Clusterpoint, Couchbase, MarkLogic, MongoDB
- **Como Chave-valor**

  - Dynamo, FoundationDB, MemcacheDB, Redis, Riak, FairCom c-treeACE
- **Como Grafo**

  - Allegro, Neo4J, OrientDB, Virtuoso

Um banco de dados orientado a objeto normalmente guarda **um objeto de uma linguagem conhecida**, como o [Zope Object Database](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/) que guarda objetos [python](/questions/tagged/python), sem necessariamente haver uma transliteração de dados.

Sutilmente diferente, um banco de dados orientado a documento (que costuma-se confundir com um banco de dados orientado a objeto) **armazena documentos em algum formato específico**. Por exemplo, o MongoDB armazena documentos em formato [bson](/questions/tagged/bson) ("Binary JSON", ou "JSON Binário"), que é uma variação do [json](/questions/tagged/json). Para este caso, para um documento se transformar num objeto, teria que ter uma tradução (ou transliteração de dados) do documento para o objeto da linguagem em questão.

Adicionalmente, há os bancos de dados que armazenam chave-valor, ou seja, um grande *array* associativo em que cada índice armazena uma estrutura de dados complexa, e os bancos que armazenam colunas, que são como documentos, mas com cada coluna tendo um valor de *timestamp* próprio.