# O que é um banco NoSQL? Como é o seu funcionamento?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, nosql

Ouvi muito a respeito sobre banco de dados NoSQL. Pesquisando sobre o mesmo encontrei a seguinte definição:

> **NoSQL** *(ás vezes interpretado como Not Only SQL - Não Somente SQL) é um
>   termo genérico para uma classe definida de banco de dados
>   não-relacionais que rompe uma longa história de banco de dados
>   relacionais com propriedades ACID*

Fonte: [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

Eu tenho mais familiaridade com banco de dados relacionais, agora com o início da popularização do NoSQL fiquei intrigado com o mesmo, porém, ainda não consegui compreender o seu conceito. Afinal, o que é um banco de dados NoSQL? Se por definição ele *não é somente SQL*, como ele funciona?

Comment: Relacionado: [NoSQL é tão problemático quanto parece?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/91)

Comment: Relacionado: ["NoSQL é sinônimo de Banco de Dados Orientado a Objetos?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19076/215)

Comment: [Veja aqui](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/17043/banco-de-dados/nosql-voce-realmente-sabe-do-que-estamos-falando/?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Esta definição já passou por mudanças e nem todo mundo concorda com elas. Há quem diga que o nome correto da tecnologia [deveria ser NoRel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#History). Em alguns casos NoSchema, porque é isso que realmente ele é. Mas na verdade o que mais ele tem de diferente é que ele é NoACID, e isso pode ser um problema.

Eu já não gosto muito do termo porque ele acabou englobando um grupo de tecnologias cuja única ligação é que são bancos de dados que não possuem relacionamento, mas elas são muito diferentes, isto nem deveria ser considerado tecnologia unicamente, parece que o termo foi criado só pra se contrapor a uma tecnologia estabelecida e desafiá-la, seja o SQL ou o relacional.

Basicamente é poder acessar os dados de forma não relacional como são a maioria dos banco de dados *mainstream*. E como o SQL é a linguagem padrão dos banco de dados relacionais, se usou este termo como marketing.

Normalmente os dados são organizados sem a criação de um esquema e sem a definição de tabelas. As principais formas de acesso aos dados são os pares de chave e valor e os documentos livres. Ainda existem modelos baseados em objetos, documentos, grafos, forma híbridas, entre outras.

NoSQL não é solução mágica para substituir os banco de dados relacionais. Ele é útil em certos cenários, principalmente quando se busca **escalabilidade horizontal** - onde novos servidores são adicionados para aumentar a capacidade (os relacionais podem fazer isto também, mas não é tão fácil).

É raro a necessidade do NoSQL para o *core* do trabalho de banco de dados, principalmente agora que a maioria deles possuem facilidades para trabalhar com **dados menos estruturados**. Mas o principal motivo é que a maioria dos problemas exigem dados tabulares e relacionados.

De fato esta era uma vantagem do NoSQL, ele permite ter dados de forma mais livre. Os "bancos de dados SQL" sempre permitiram isto mas não era tão simples e era pouco óbvio para alguns. Eles se modernizaram desde 2009 quando o tal NoSQL se tornou conhecido.

E lembrando que o uso de chave e valor é uma das [formas normais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) de um banco de dados relacional. Claro que ele não é otimizado para isto.

[Tem uma pergunta aqui para entender um pouco melhor que ele é útil em casos de grande escala](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101). Eu costumo dizer que nem todo mundo é o Facebook, NetFlix ou Google, então nem todo mundo precisa dele. As pessoas adotam por moda ou desconhecimento do modelo relacional e do que esses DBs podem fazer.

- Ele não é simples de consultar de formas diversas.
- Ele não tem boa performance em certos cenários.
- Ele não tem consistência garantida como no banco de dados relacional.

É a briga do [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) X BASE. Há muitos cenários que a consistência precisa em tempo real é necessária. Ver sobre [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

Alguns DBs NoSQL são *full* [ACID (veja os detalhes)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101), mas costumam ter desvantagens em relação aos outros. Embora há controvérsias se isto é NoSQL mesmo, porque a ideia do NoSQL não é abandonar o SQL e sim o modelo relacional.

Na verdade o nome correto deste tipo de tecnologia devia ser NoConsistency porque é isso que realmente não tem. Cada vez mais elas estão usando relações e até SQL.

Pra falar a verdade boa parte deles usaram um modelo diferente para sair da concorrência forte dos DBs que eram usados, hoje eles querem ser DBs de uso geral, e assim como os relacionais podem fazer tudo o que o NoSQL podia, o NoSQL quer poder fazer o que o relacional pode, abrindo mão de alguma outra coisa, ou seja, você escolhe que defeito aceitar ter, afinal o CAP theorem continua existindo, a despeito que alguns acharem que é possível quebrar isso (ninguém conseguiu).

É comum usá-lo como adição ao SQL, como cache ou distribuição. É ótimo quando os dados são efêmeros ou podem estar atrasados. Se dão bem quando as consultas são simples e não relacionadas.

O maior abuso é no modelo de documento, quase sempre o relacional é melhor. Os outros modelos as pessoas até usam razoavelmente onde precisa.

## Funcionamento

Como cada modelo funciona diferentemente, e principalmente como cada produto tem sua forma de trabalhar, não há um padrão - uma das críticas que se faz a este tipo de tecnologia - fica complicado dizer como funciona. Cada caso é diferente. Mas dá para dar alguns exemplos genéricos.

#### Chave-valor

No modelo de chave e valor, você tem um [dicionário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) enorme. Assim como uma estrutura de dicionário em qualquer linguagem, o acesso é sempre feito pela chave, muito provavelmente através do cálculo de uma função *hash*. Então você pede o valor de uma chave a especificando. Simples assim.

Normalmente isto funciona bem em memória, mas não costuma ir bem se os dados estão em disco.

É comum que o valor retornado seja algo simples, um dado que equivaleria a uma coluna em um SGDB relacional. Mas nada impede que venha uma tupla com várias colunas.

#### Documento

No modelo de documento tem várias formas de acesso, pode-se pedir por um valor que será buscado em todos membros de todos os documentos ou pode especificar o tipo de dado, aí será seletivo em quais partes do documento a busca será feita. Claro que documentos que não tenham este membro, não serão avaliados.

Em geral estes documentos são armazenados como JSON ou XML, mas outros formatos são usados também.

Normalmente o acesso é feito como estruturas de dados em memória. Por isto é comum que eles estejam em memória mesmo. O programador pressupõe isto. Quando se usa o relacional, apesar que o cache do DB colocar muita coisa em memória, não há garantias disto, então sempre tem que pensar as consultas como se estivesse em disco. Ainda que hoje, com SSD e NVRAM, o custo de acesso ao armazenamento de massa permanente ficou mais baixo. Portanto a tendência é haver menos necessidade do seu uso, e mais pessoas usarão só porque está na moda.

#### Grafos

Também engloba os orientados a objeto que não deixam de ser [grafos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240230/101). O uso geral é útil para casos bem complexos que envolvem relacionamentos não estruturados como um [grafo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239214/101) mesmo.

#### Colunar

Quando os atributos individuais são mais importantes que o item como um todo, dividindo assim em *clusters*. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232371/101).

[Exemplos](http://nosql-database.org/).

[Saiba mais](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nosqlKeyPoints.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).