# Quais são os cenários apropriados para bancos de dados baseados em grafos

Tags: banco-de-dados, grafo, nosql, neo4j

Ultimamente tenho estudado o banco de dados baseado em grafos [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com).

Tendo em vista que a grande maioria das aplicações atuais utilizam-se de bancos de dados relacionais tradicionais, pergunto:

- Quais são os cenários apropriados para utilizar este tipo de banco de dados?
- Quais seriam os principais prós e contras?
- No cenário nacional (brasileiro), há adesão deste tipo de banco de dados em cenários de produção?

Comment: cara sou analista desenvolvedor faz um tempinho e nunca vi um DB orientado a grafos mas le esse artigo aqui: https://medium.com/accendis-tech/uma-gentil-introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-uso-de-banco-de-dados-orientados-a-grafos-com-neo4j-ca148df2d352

Comment: Existe alguma pergunta/resposta canônica aqui no SOpt sobre o que é um banco de dados baseado em grafos? Creio que seria uma ótima para existir aqui

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, perfeito. [Aqui está](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240230/o-que-%C3%A9-um-banco-de-dados-baseado-em-grafos).

Comment: Eu tenho para mim que eles são adequados para construir relacionamentos envolvendo nós e arestas, como no grafo dos relacionamentos em uma rede social como Facebook ou Linkedin. Mas é um completo chute da minha parte.

Comment: @Piovezan seu comentário é o que mais se aproxima de uma resposta apropriada.

Answer (score 4):

Nenhum :P

Claro que há. A questão é que é possível usar o banco de dados relacional para fazer grafos já que estes estão em um nível acima do relacional e cada vez mais os principais softwares de banco de dados vão disponibilizando facilidades para lidar com nós e arestas, mas são só facilidades, elas não são necessárias.

Estes bancos de dados fazem marketing de que possuem melhor performance, mas isto é só questão de organização dos dados. Não tem milagre, é como o NoSQL, é rápido em certas circunstâncias abrindo mão de alguma coisa para ser rápido.

Muitas vezes as pessoas usam sem perceber, mas de forma geral os cenários são limitados já que ele é útil em casos de dados completamente sem estrutura que precisam se formando conforme a necessidade sem muito critério, o que é raro. Geralmente são problemas científicos bastante complexos os de processos bastante abertos, possivelmente que envolvam máquina de aprendizado, inteligência artificial, redes neurais, etc.

A única grande vantagem do banco de dados específico para grafo é as facilidades de lidar com este formato já que tudo o que em tese ele oferece, pode ser feito em outros bancos de dados com um mínimo de recursos ou baixo nível suficiente para simular tudo na mão. Li sobre vantagens e elas só existem pela organização, não pelo software em si. Claro que simular um grafo em um banco de dados relacional tende a ser mais difícil, especialmente se quiser a mesma performance e é mais fácil cometer erros.

Quando deseja fazer algo que seja diferente de um grafo tem enorme dificuldade ou impossibilidade. Ele não possui transações e as facilidades que consultas que o relacional oferece.

Eu li sobre vantagens que na verdade é característica de um software específico e não do modelo.

O segredo da performance dele é usar apontadores de dados, algo que é só você criar nas suas tabelas. Ele não é mágico, é só uma técnica básica e até muito simples para quem entende os fundamentos da computação.

O Brasil não é uma ilha, assim como tem utilização fora, tem aqui, mas ainda é bem limitado. Continuará sendo com a adesão dos relacionais à esta modalidade, afinal é comum que apenas parte do problema se beneficie dos grafos, outras partes ainda se beneficiarão do relacional e outras formas, então um sistema que não se prenda a uma forma tende a ter mais sucesso.

Entenda que o relacional não fez tanto sucesso assim a toa. A maioria das modalidades concorrentes existem há décadas também e não fazem sucesso tão grande porque eles não são tão úteis em muitos cenários, o relacional é. Mesmo NoSQL que parece fazer sucesso agora, se fala mais do que se usa. E se usa mais do que deveria. Tem muitos casos que é uma opção igual ou pior ao relacional, mas o modismo faz ser adotado.

O sucesso de muitas novidades se dá porque as pessoas só seguem receitas de bolo e não entendem como resolver os problemas com as ferramentas que já existem. Então na verdade o que traz sucesso é ter algo pronto para as pessoas usarem e não novas capacidades.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Usar um banco de dados relacional para simular uma estrutura de grafo é um erro, visto que estes não utilizam um [armazenamento de grafo nativo ou processamento de grafo nativo](https://neo4j.com/blog/native-vs-non-native-graph-technology/). As facilidades referidas por você no primeiro parágrafo são muito importantes quando lidando com dados altamente conectados. A adjacência  livre de índice (sobre a qual você pode ler no link acima) permite que você navegue entre as conexões dos seus nós utilizando índices locais, sem a necessidade de recorrer a índices globais.

Comment: Em relação a performance, não é apenas questão de organização dos dados. Em cenários onde seu conjunto de dados é altamente conectado (como o clássico caso de das redes sociais, por exemplo) realizar operações de busca em bancos de dados baseados em grafos mostra-se extremamente mais eficaz, principalmente para buscas minimamente mais profundas.

Comment: Quando você fala que " Ele não possui transações" está se referindo a quem? O [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/), por exemplo, é um banco de dados ACID, assim como a grande maioria dos bancos de dados relacionais. Também, bancos de dados baseados em grafos se encaixam na categoria de bancos de dados NoSQL, diferente do que sua resposta parece afirmar quando diz " Não tem milagre, é como o NoSQL, é rápido em certas circunstâncias abrindo mão de alguma coisa para ser rápido."

Comment: @BrunoPeres Transação e ACID são coisas distintas, tem controle sobre essas transações como nos relacionais? Quando tem ACID mantêm as outras características propagandeadas? Preciso refrasear a parte do NoSQL.

Comment: Sim, você tem controle sobre as transações. E não, não há perda de característica.

Comment: Acho improvável, ou eles conseguiram fazer milagre, mas pelo jeito você já sabia a resposta que queria.

Comment: Qual característica seria perdida? Talvez eu não tenha entendido o que ê quis dizer. Na verdade eu costumo estudar este tipo de solução e tentei fomentar este tema no SO-pt (inclusive oferecendo uma recompensa). Vejo algumas afirmações muito vazias nas sua resposta, como por exemplo _"é útil em casos de dados completamente sem estrutura que precisam se formando conforme a necessidade sem muito critério"_. Esse definitivamente não é um use case no qual seria vantajoso utilizar um graph database.

Comment: Outro exemplo: _Geralmente são problemas científicos bastante complexos os de processos bastante abertos, possivelmente que envolam máquina de aprendizado, inteligência artificial, redes neurais, etc._ Esse casos citados são relacionados a [engines de processamento de grafos] e não a bancos de dados baseados em grafos.

Answer (score -3):

**Quais são os cenários apropriados para utilizar este tipo de banco de dados?**

Senários em que a performance é necessária e onde os dados não são organizados. Uma referência legal para isso é [BigData](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWhIyB5MLWAhWFhZAKHX-9BEIQFghJMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sas.com%2Fpt_br%2Finsights%2Fbig-data%2Fwhat-is-big-data.html&usg=AFQjCNH9Y4095AxZOlwhLc20NDljWv2W-Q).

**Quais seriam os principais prós e contras?**

A primeira pergunta responde a segunda. Não existe prós ou contras, o que existe é o uso errado da tecnologia. Recomendo [http://luizpicolo.com.br/2014/02/27/xiismo-tecnológico/](http://luizpicolo.com.br/2014/02/27/xiismo-tecnol%C3%B3gico/)

**No cenário nacional (brasileiro), há adesão deste tipo de banco de dados em cenários de produção?**

Desconheço empresas que usam em produção e com 100% de uso. Porém se o escopo pedir, não vejo problema em usar.