# O que é um banco de dados baseado em grafos?

Tags: banco-de-dados, grafo, nosql

Não encontrei neste site a resposta para esta pergunta. Então, minha questão é basicamente esta:

O que é um banco de dados baseado em grafos?

Answer (score 14):

Diferente dos bancos de dados relacionais o **Banco de dados orientado a grafos** possui outras formas de persistência de dados o [NoSQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

A ideia é criar um modelo `menos genérico` que o modelo relacional, proporcionando uma modelagem mais simples, buscando obter maior performance, tanto por sua implementação livre de operações custosas como `JOINs`, quanto pelo uso de algoritmos de grafos.

Sendo muito mais simples de desenhar ele não precisa de um design complexo de tabelas para começar a incluir os dados.

Imagine-se criando uma entidade aluno, basta criar um `nó` e suas `propriedades` sem se preocupar inicialmente com quais relacionamentos possuirá.

A grande diferença está na representação do relacionamento entre os dados.

Temos as entidades chamadas de `vértices` ou `nós` que são ligadas pelas `arestas` ou `relacionamentos` cada um podendo guardar dados entre os relacionamentos e cada relacionamento pode ter uma `direção`.

Na imagem abaixo os `vértices` são representados pelos círculos vermelhos e as `arestas` pelas setas:

[image: Exemplo]

Exemplos de bancos de dados orientado a grafos [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) e [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/orientdb/)

O `Neo4j` implementa a propriedade do modelo grafo sendo eficiente até o nível de armazenamento. Fornece características de banco de dados completo, incluindo `ACID`, suporte de `cluster`, tornando-o adequado para usar dados grafos em produção.

Sua linguagem oficial é o [Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_Query_Language) que permite buscar, criar e modificar estruturas baseadas em um grafo de informações e relacionamentos.

Exemplo de comando:

```
start programmer=(3)
match (programmer)-[:PAIRED]->(pair)
where pair.age > 30 
return pair
order by pair.age
skip 5 limit 10
```

Links onde busquei informações:

https://medium.com/accendis-tech/uma-gentil-introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-uso-de-banco-de-dados-orientados-a-grafos-com-neo4j-ca148df2d352

http://nicholasess.com.br/neo4j-2/bem-vindo-ao-neo4j/

https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/graphdb-series-o-que-e-um-banco-de-dados-de-grafos/?trace=1519021197&source=single

http://bcc.ime.usp.br/tccs/2016/taksqth/downloads/poster.pdf

http://orientdb.com/orientdb/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_Query_Language

Comment: Achei seu texto confuso