# Diferença entre modelos de banco de dados não relacionais

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, nosql

Quando se trata de banco de dados não relacionais, temos algumas opções, como o *document database* e *graph database*.

Em relação as duas, quais as principais diferenças e benefícios do uso de cada uma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como o próprio nome diz um banco de dados orientado a documento tem como base de seus dados um documento com todas as informações que precisa sobre ele. Mesmo dados relacionados costumam estar no próprio documento e você tem coleções desses documentos. Já [falei sobre o MongoDB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274320/101), o mais usado neste modelo. Visualizando:

[image: Document]

Um banco de dados baseado em grafos tem como ponto forte as relações entre os diversos objetos e estas relações podem ocorrer de diversas formas, não há muita regra de como eles se relacionam. Eu [já respondi sobre isso antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239214/101). Visualizando:

[image: Grafo]

Os dois se contrapõem ao modelo relacional que tem documentos (tabelas) mais rígidas (isso já não é tão verdade em sistemas mais modernos) e relações entre esses dados de forma mais restrita, o que pode ser vantajoso em um ponto e desvantajoso de um outro. Alguns produtos que eram banco de dados relacionais puros agora trabalham com multi modelo e já há bancos dados não relacionais adotando mais de um modelo, então essa ideia de separar os produtos por modelos começa a ficar mais nebulosa. Adote o modelo que mais encaixa com o problema (não o que você mais gosta de trabalhar) e veja quais produtos atendem isto. Como boa parte das aplicações exigem mais de um modelo os melhores produtos são os que atendem essa demanda de forma nativa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Na verdade conheço 4 tipos principais:

- **Chave valor:** é precisamente o que o nome descreve você tem uma chave e um valor, o uso geralmente é para os casos onde você faz buscas somente pela chave, não sendo possível buscar pelo valor, casos de uso desse modelo geralmente são armazenamento de sessões de usuários e carrinhos de compras, exemplificando, você tem o id do usuário que é a chave e os itens do carrinho ou as informações da sessão do usuário. Bancos: Dynamo, Riak.
- **Documento:** é um tipo de chave valor, a grande diferença é que você tem varias chaves e valores e consegue buscar por ambos. Os casos de uso deste modelo são logs de eventos, gerenciamento de conteúdo, blogs e afins. Bancos:  MongoDB, Apache CouchDB.
- **Coluna:** este é particularmente um dos que eu menos entendi ainda e estou ainda estudando, mas a ideia aqui é parecida com um banco relacional, somente a ideia de ter colunas, então você vai ter colunas e linhas quase parecido com um banco relacional, casos de uso são praticamente os mesmos de banco de dados via documento, o que diferencia um do outro é que aqui você tem que criar a "tabela" com as colunas enquanto no banco de dados de documento não. Bancos Cassandra, HBase.
- **Grafo:** este é valido para modelos de dados onde é importante o relacionamento entre eles e o relacionamento é complexo, por exemplo você quer saber se o João e a Maria foram no restaurante Y. Os casos de uso mais comuns para este modelo são redes sociais e serviços baseados em localização. Bancos: Apache Giraph, Neo4J.

Aconselho a ler o livro: NoSQL Distilled do Martin Fowler, acho que tem em português, foi um dos primeiros que li e me ajudaram. Tambem tem uma palestra legal dele no youtube sobre isso. Embora as referencias sejam um pouco antigas os conceitos mudam pouco.